# change string to float in a list

Tags: python, python-2.7

I want to find "elevation" in a file and change the string to float ,for example, I use regular expression to find "13,804 feet" and would like to change to [13804.0, "feet"], also if there is 'Sea level', it should be changed to [0.0,""]. I write the following function, it works for the "13,804 feet" situation, but it does not work for "Sea level"

```
import locale
def elevationToFloat(x):
    elevation = []
    reNum = re.compile(r"""(?P<number>[-,0-9]+)\s+(?P<suffix>[a-zA-Z]+)?""")
    new = reNum.findall(x)
    for i in new:
        temp = i[0].replace(",", "")
        elevation.append(float(temp))
        elevation.append(i[1])
    return elevation

print elevationToFloat("-70,222 feet")  (it gives me [-70222.0, 'feet'])
print elevationToFloat("Sea level")     (does not work)
```

actually I tried for a long time for the "sea level"situation (it is too messy so I think I will not post the wrong code), but it does not work. Can anyone help me to improve my code

Comment: `it is too messy so I think I will not post the wrong code` -- No, unless you post your code no-one will be able to tell you where you went wrong.  Or are you looking for _ready to eat_ solutions?

Comment: What kind of file is it?

Comment: txt file I just want to write a function and demonstrate that at least it works. However, i am struggling with how to change "Sea level"

Comment: You are trying to use a single function for both "-70,222 feet" and "Sea level". And your regular expression, re.compile and reNum.findall will not work for both. It is better to use one more method for "Sea level", if u cannot handle it in a single method.

Comment: finally I got it done by myself. Thank you for all your reply